# Android Studio Chipmunk 2021.2.1 - SMS Messages wont work 5/25/2022

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, sms, android-permissions

I have been working to make a simple SMS app with Android Studio Chipmunk 2021.2.1, but none of my attempts to receive SMS have worked.

I am able to send messages from the emulator and on my devices. Although, I can't receive SMS messages with help from any example or tutorial I have found, using a device or emulator.

I have followed these solutions, only to find out something with them didn't work, a depreciated include files or depreciated dependency or uses an *old* API.

Is there a place where **current** example of how to send an SMS?

**Things I've tried**

- https://google-developer-training.github.io/android-developer-phone-sms-course/Lesson%202/2_p_sending_sms_messages.html
- https://github.com/google-developer-training/android-fundamentals-phone-sms
- https://programmingdigest.com/receiving-and-sending-application-in-android-studio/
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9iJ0EaP-fAQ
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pke6sMxOsuw
- My own attempts - many,Many times guided by **Android Developer**,
  nothing works.

I have tried several different versions of broadcasters, manifests and classes, and nothing works to receive SMS messages.

I made a method in the main_activity.java:

`public void logIt(String msg){ Log.e("TAG", "LogIt : "+msg); return; }`

.. then call that method in the `onReceive` class to show any output like :

`logIt("BroadcastReceiver called because of an SMS");`

.. but when the device or emulator receives a message it doesn't run the code in the `onReceive` or my custom method. I am not sure where the problem is, I can't seem to test if an SMS intent is received, if my app even sees SMS Intents, my 'logcat' never shows an SMS was received. I have added permissions to the manifest file, and created separate .java files to house the custom handlers for incoming SMS'. But, in the end nothing happens with some of the versions. Some versions give me other errors about the code used. Even the Google example on GitHub does not work, after fixing many errors it gives, It gives an error I can't find the answer to fix, "error: package R does not exist `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`"

Could someone please show me an example of a current working Android Studio (JAVA) 'how-to' that can receive SMS messages?

Thank You

Comment: For future reference, this isn't really an appropriate site to ask for someone to put together a complete working example from nothing. Even if it's not working, we'd prefer to see whatever you've got, at least to get a sense of where you're at currently. That said, this is pretty much the bare minimum necessary to receive SMS on standard Android: https://drive.google.com/file/d/12RJh5jN1OKLvDhxMnQNlFNVTqz4hWTn7/view?usp=sharing.

Comment: I was suggested to ask here, none of my friends knew the answer and I could not find the link you just gave me.

Thank you very much for the link to google drive, I found Google's GitHub page with a non-working SMS example. But thank you, I will scamper off with the link you gave me. I am glad to know Google made a current working example.

Comment: No worries. You're fine. I was just giving you a heads up. You did a good job of showing us your research and explaining your attempts. We just like to see your current code to be sure that we're all on the same page. Btw, that example is not official Google or anything; it's mine. I figured I'd put together a minimal one real quick before you got a copy/paste answer with a bunch of irrelevant junk in it. Cheers!